# apply a function to each pair of rows of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of size `4x400`. I want to apply a function to all pairs of rows of this numpy array. 
The function:

```
def func(vector1,vector2):
    ...
    ...
    return X
```

where `X` is a float value.

So in the end I will get a vector of length 10.

Is there any way to this efficiently (fast) without using loops?

Comment: I didnt downvote ... but you are likely going to give us a small self contained code example if you want an answer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy
import itertools as it
arr=numpy.random.rand(4,400)
transposed=arr.T
values=[numpy.dot(i,j) for i, j in it.combinations(transposed, 2)]
print values
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u will have to use loop. Use itertools in python to generate all combinations of rows
This may help you https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html.. Then apply your function on all generated pairs

Comment: Certainly need a loop or comprehension list. Loops are probably the most basic and needed programming skill. If your not efficient in loops I would seriously brush up on them, or else you will never be able to handle data.

Comment: did it. without loops. see my own answer.